# Can I use an input variable to start an animation in a child component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an animation I want to execute when an *ngFor loop finishes

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.items.changes.subscribe(t =>{
   Promise.resolve().then(t => {
     this.everythingLoaded();
   })
  })
 }
```

When they are finished I call the everythingLoaded function that emits an event to the parent component to change a value from hide to show

```
 everythingLoaded(){
   this.showAnimation.emit();
 }

<app-photo-display [animateHide]=animateHide (showAnimation)='setShow()'></app-photo-display>
```

Then that function changes the input property that is controlling my animation

```
animations: [
    trigger('animState' , [
      state('show', style({
       opacity: 1
      })),
      state('hide', style({
        opacity: 0 
      })),
      transition('show => hide', animate('600ms ease-out')),
      transition('hide => show', animate('1000ms ease-in'))
    ])
  ]

<img [@animState]="doWeShow ? 'show' : 'hide'" *ngFor="let item of items;">
```

The animation isn't being triggered on the change of my input value

```
 hideAnimation(){
    this.animateHide = false;
  }
  setShow(){
    this.animateHide = true;
  }
```

The hideAnimation function is triggered on a nav click to hide the current images while others load then after all the images load the input property should be updated via the event emitter to show the images with the animation.

Sorry that was long winded thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering your `animation` with `doWeShow` but actually never changing the value from `doWeShow`, but instead you are only changing the value of `this.animateHide` to `show` or `hide` And pushing it in component as `input`. Also make sure that your component `<app-photo-display>` has `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` set. Have a look over here: https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/09/27/angular-performances-part-4/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was setting doWeShow using the animateHide property. @Input('animateHide') doWeShow: string; I have since changed it to a boolean that is either true or false. [@animState]="doWeShow ? 'show' : 'hide' ". I'm also using ngOnChanges to look for the changing input variables but I will also include your changeDetection suggestion.

Comment: Great, hope it works for you! Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most!